# Jquery Accordion Form Wrap

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui-accordion

My Jquery accordion form works perfectly unless i pull the  tag around the whole box. The idea was to separate the forms because there will be a lot of information to collect.

http://www.bigwavemedia.co.uk/test/ (Working version with Form tag inside one of the accordions)

http://www.bigwavemedia.co.uk/test/index.php/stack (Breaks when i move the form tag around the whole accordion system)

code ---> working version

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="preOrderTop">
        <h1>Pre Order</h1>
    </div>

       <?php 

        $this->load->helper("form");
        echo validation_errors();
        echo "<div id='accordion'>";




        echo  "<h3>Party Details</h3>";

        echo  $message;

        echo  form_open("welcome/send_email");

        echo form_label("Name:", "name");
        $data = array(
            "name" => "fullName",
            "id" => "fullName",
            "value" => set_value("fullName")

        );
        echo form_input($data);



        echo form_label("Email:", "email");
        $data = array(
            "name" => "email",
            "id" => "email",
            "value" => set_value("email")
        );
        echo form_input($data);



        echo form_label("Telephone", "telephone");
        $data = array(
            "name" => "telephone",
            "id" => "telephone",
            "value" => set_value("telephone")
        );
        echo form_input($data);



        echo form_label("date", "date");
        $data = array(
            "name" => "date",
            "id" => "date",
            "value" => set_value("date")
        );
        echo form_input($data);



        echo "<br>";

        echo form_submit("contactSubmit", "send");

        echo form_close();
    ?>


    <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <div>
        <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
    </div>
        <h3>Section 3</h3>
        <div>
        <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
        <ul>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
        </ul>



        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

But when i wrap the whole form tag around the accordion it breaks? I have no idea how to fix this, its driving me bananas.

-> Code with form wrapped around

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="preOrderTop">
    <h1>Pre Order</h1>
  </div>
  <?php 

        $this->load->helper("form");
        echo validation_errors();
            echo  $message;

        echo  form_open("welcome/send_email");
        echo "<div id='accordion'>";




        echo  "<h3>Party Details</h3>";

        echo  $message;

        echo  form_open("welcome/send_email");

        echo form_label("Name:", "name");
        $data = array(
            "name" => "fullName",
            "id" => "fullName",
            "value" => set_value("fullName")

        );
        echo form_input($data);



        echo form_label("Email:", "email");
        $data = array(
            "name" => "email",
            "id" => "email",
            "value" => set_value("email")
        );
        echo form_input($data);



        echo form_label("Telephone", "telephone");
        $data = array(
            "name" => "telephone",
            "id" => "telephone",
            "value" => set_value("telephone")
        );
        echo form_input($data);



        echo form_label("Date", "date");
        $data = array(
            "name" => "date",
            "id" => "date",
            "value" => set_value("date")
        );
        echo form_input($data);



        echo "<br>";

    ?>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 3</h3>
  <div>
    <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
    <ul>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
      <li>List item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <?php     
        echo form_submit("contactSubmit", "send");

        echo form_close();
        ?>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Please show specific examples of code. Links to other pages that require users to use developer tools to diagnose are not useful and 90% of the time, no one will answer you

Comment: Updated, why was this voted down?

Comment: For the reasons zgr mentioned. Put HTML in your question, not server-side code.

Comment: Sorry, has anyone got a reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

After more research I discovered this accordion menu does not work with forms, after using another one it worked perfectly first time.